# Recover obscured pixels

Tags: iphone, security, image-capture, image-processing

If I screenshot something on my phone and scribble out the text:
[image]

Is it possible to get the text back?

Are there computer programs that can analyse that jpg to see what’s under the scribble.

Comment: Can't write answer now but all info is here https://9to5mac.com/2018/03/13/ios-markup-reveal-redact-sensitive-info/

Comment: I'm one of those PITA people who never takes a chance. I REMOVE any text I want redacted, screencap it and then fill the empty box with black, That way there is nothing to recover. Sure it is not likely that your friends have NSA level image recovery tools, but it is so easy to leave nothing to analyze.

Comment: This has been covered a couple of times on Security SE & the answer is basically "it depends on how you obscured it" - https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/184099/secure-way-of-masking-out-sensitive-information-in-screenshots/184100#184100

Comment: @tetsujin it is obscured with the screenshot annotation pen tool

Answer (score 1):

If you are scribbling the text while still editing the screenshot, you can press the undo button to restore the original image, press the Done button and select Save to Photos.

If you have saved the screenshot to Photos after scribbling the text, there is no way to revert the image and restore the original one.